# Haskell Stack Implementation not working as expected

Tags: haskell, stack

I am self-learning Haskell and I implemented a stack as follows:

```
pop :: [a] -> [a]
pop [] = error "Cannot pop from an empty list!"
pop xs = init xs

push :: a -> [a] -> [a]
push = (:)

peek :: [a] -> a
peek [] = error "Cannot peek from an empty list!"
peek (x:xs) = last (x:xs)


isEmpty :: [Int] -> Bool
isEmpty [] = True
isEmpty xs = False

test :: [Int] -> Either String [Int]
test = fmap reverse . foldM step []
    where step xs x | even x = Right (push x xs)
                    | odd x = do
                        var <- Right (pop xs)
                        if isEmpty var then Left "Successful"
                        else (if not (isEmpty var) then return xs else Left "Unsuccessful")
```

There is no problem with pushing a value to the stack, however, this implementation cannot pop from the stack as expected, for example:

```
Input: [0,2,3,1]
Output: Right [0,2]
Expected: Left "Successful"
```

I think the problem lies within the `do` segment of the `test` function, but I am struggling to make it work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You push from the left, but peek and pop from the right. That's not how a stack works.

Comment: Apart from that, note that the `do` block isn't really ... _doing_ anything at all, it's just stripping out the value again that you just put into the `Right` constructor.

Comment: Should I change ```push = (:)``` to ```push x xs = xs ++ [x]```, or do something with the ```test``` function to make it push from the right as well?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I see. What I was trying to do there was to pop the stack then immediately check if the resulting stack is empty or not... so perhaps the ```do``` block doesn't really work that way?

Comment: What you're describing seems to be simply `isEmpty $ pop xs`.

Comment: Yup, I found the problem to be the ```do``` loop and the ```then return xs``` part. Now it works fine, thanks!

Comment: @jk_01 post your answer in the answer section and you can mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from the comments, the `test` function now works using the following implementation:

```
test :: [Int] -> Either String [Int]
test = fmap reverse . foldM step []
    where step xs x | even x = Right (push x xs)
                    | odd x = if isEmpty (pop xs) then Left "Successful"
                        else (if not (isEmpty (pop xs)) then return (pop xs) else Left "Unsuccessful")
```